# JavaScript: For loops to create copies of a picture don't work

Tags: javascript, html, image, loops, object

I'm making a platformer in JavaScript and HTML, and I've run into a problem. Some code that is supposed to duplicate and print an image of a box (the floor that the character walks on) isn't working, and is thus just displaying a white screen when I run it. I have checked the console of my browser, but it says there are no errors. Here's the HTML file:

```
<body onkeydown="keyDown(event)" onkeyup="keyUp(event)">
<canvas id="graphics" width=600 height=400 style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;"></canvas>

<script>
//VARIABLES
var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("graphics");
var grafx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");
var player = new GameObject("Character1NoAA.png",100,100,64,59);
var maxBlock = 4;
var block = new Array();
for (var i=0;i<=maxBlock;i++) {
    block[i] = new GameObject("Block.png",i*62+100,300,62,62);
}

var img = new Image();
img.src = "Character1NoAA.png";
var isLeft = false;
var isRight = false;
var isUp = false;
player.Gravity = 20;
player.Weight = 0.3;

//EVENTS
function keyDown(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "%") isLeft = true;
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "'") isRight = true;
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === " ") isUp = true;
}
function keyUp(e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "%") isLeft = false;
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === "'") isRight = false;
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode) === " ") isUp = false;
}

//MAINLOOP
MainLoop();
function MainLoop() {
    //PRE VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS
    player.X += player.Velocity_X;
    player.Y += player.Velocity_Y;
    player.Velocity_X = player.Velocity_X * 0.90

    //LOGIC
    if (isLeft) player.Velocity_X = -4;
    if (isRight) player.Velocity_X = 4;
    if (!isLeft && !isRight) player.Velocity = 0;
    if (player.Velocity_Y < player.Gravity) player.Velocity_Y += player.Weight;
    for (var i=0;i<=maxBlock;i++){
        if (player.isColliding(block[i]) && player.Y + player.Height < block[i].Y + player.Velocity_Y) {
            player.Y = block[i].Y - player.Height;
            player.Velocity_Y = 0;
        }
    }
    }
    if (isUp && player.Velocity_Y === 0) {
        player.Velocity_Y += -10;
    }
    //POST VARIABLE ADJUSTMENTS

    //RENDERING

    grafx.clearRect(0,0,gameCanvas.width, gameCanvas.height);
    grafx.drawImage(player.Sprite,player.X,player.Y);
    for (var i=0;i<=maxBlock;i++) {
        grafx.drawImage(block[i].Sprite,block[i].X,block[i].Y);
        setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60);
    }


function GameObject(img,x,y,width,height) {
    this.Sprite = new Image();
    this.Sprite.src = img;
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
    this.Previous_X = this.X;
    this.Previous_Y = this.Y;
    this.Velocity_X = 0;
    this.Velocity_Y = 0;
    this.Width = width;
    this.Height = height;
    this.Gravity = 0;
    this.Weight = 0;

    this.isColliding = function(obj) {
        if (this.X > obj.X + obj.Width) return false;
        else if (this.X + this.Width < obj.X) return false;
        else if (this.Y > obj.Y + obj.Height) return false;
        else if (this.Y + this.Height < obj.Y) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

In this code, the for loops at `//VARIABLES`, `//LOGIC` and `//RENDERING` are supposed to work with the `GameObject` at the bottom of the code to produce 4 copies (a number defined by the `maxBlock` variable) of a picture of a box, and append them to the array `block`. I'm pretty sure I haven't made a spelling error, as I've looked over it numerous times and fixed the only bugs I could find. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: changed by answer. see if that works.

Comment: See my revised answer below on moving the setTimeout outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THere is one BIG FIX needs to be made I didn't notice the first time:

```
for (var i=0;i<=maxBlock;i++) {
    grafx.drawImage(block[i].Sprite,block[i].X,block[i].Y);
    setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60);//THIS IS BAD
}
```

You have the SetTimeout call in a for loop, meaning it gets set n-times every game loop.
Instead, move it outside the for loop

```
for (var i=0;i<=maxBlock;i++) {
    grafx.drawImage(block[i].Sprite,block[i].X,block[i].Y);
  }
setTimeout(MainLoop, 1000/60);
```

Now the character moves for me in firefox. Before it wasn't moving cause the script was essentially gagging itself on setTimeout calls.

Comment: It is in the same folder, and the URI is correct. This is a bit frustrating

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. What browser are you using?
When I run it in Google Chrome, there's a blank screen. When I run it in IE, it shows the images but the character doesn't move.

Comment: let me try in chrome... I was using FireFox.

Comment: It would appear Chrome has broken the draw image method with one of its updates. Test the following page in the browsers:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage

Comment: I don't think it's Chrome. I just tried the code in Firefox and the character didn't move, but the images did load.

Comment: Chrome is definitely the problem with drawImage. I've submitted a bug report. The keys are due to putting the setTimeout in a loop. See my revised answer above.

Comment: The answer above fixed the problem in Chrome, too. Chrome bottle necks differently then IE or firefox I guess. Restaring all browsers and testing code with the above solution worked.

Comment: That was one problem, but it turns out that the whole thing may have just been a case of mismatched curly braces. Thanks for all your help!